# After prime select graphics card not showing up in Ubuntu about

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have used `sudo prime-select nvidia` to set nvidia and then rebooted. After that `prime-select query` returns `nvidia`, but under system info the old integrated graphics still shows up:

[image]

Also I cannot see a tab "Prime profiles" under nvidia x server settings.

[image]

I want to activate my GeForce GT 1030 card. How do I know when it is activated? Is `prime-select query` telling the truth or system info?

Answer (score 1):

- Prime is for laptops with hybrid video. You have a desktop, so don't use prime-select.
- Make sure you put the GT1030 in the correct x16 slot (the black one, not the white one).
- Make sure SecureBoot is disabled in the BIOS.
- Check the BIOS for options related to GPU.
- Check output of 'glxinfo -B' to see what GPU is in use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `nvidia-driver-515-open` drivers, and I could fix it by adding `options nvidia NVreg_OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus=1` in `/etc/modprobe.d/` configuration folder, [as mentioned here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/515.43.04/README/kernel_open.html).

These are the exact steps I followed

```sh
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers-kms.conf
```

Then I added the line mentioned above. My file looked like this

```
# This file was generated by nvidia-drivers-515
# Set value to 0 to disable modesetting
options nvidia-drm modeset=1

# Custom settings
options nvidia NVreg_OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus=1
```

Then finally I selected nvidia again with `sudo prime-select nvidia`

After rebooting, Nvidia GPU was showing up in `About` Ubuntu settings section